# Can't Edit products

Tags: magento-1.9, error, products, code

I'm having problems with my Magento website.

I first noticed we had a problem when I went to: "System/Configuration/General/Design" I got the following error message:

```
"Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Helper_UnserializeArray' not found in /home/devastraantiques/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547"
```

I've since discovered that I can't Edit or even Add a product, as I now get the following error message:

"Images

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getUploaderConfig() on a non-object in /home/devastraantiques/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content.php on line 56"
```

I've been through Forums, tried numerous different things, but nothing has helped.
The only thing that changed on my site was a Security Patch.
I'm currently using Magento CE - 1.9.1.1

Can anyone help?
I'm at a loss of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is enabled.

You should disable it, flush the cache and re-compile. I assume you have access to the backend, so you can do it under System -> Tools -> Compilation.

**Update**

If you have installed SUPEE-8788, I believe you are having problems because some of your extensions or local overrides still rely on the Flash uploader. This one has been removed in this patch. See here: https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-8788 and also the 1.9.3 release notes here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1930

There's no way I could help you here, so please contact the extension providers.

Comment: I disabled it, Flushed both forms of Magento Cache, and then I re-compiled it. Still doesn't work, same exact problem.

Comment: Does it work with the compiler disabled?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Just tried.

Comment: The 2nd error points to a class path that is only present when the compiler is enabled, so at least there should be a different error.

Comment: With it disabled - edit product results in:

"
Images

Fatal error: Call to a member function getUploaderConfig() on a non-object in /home/devastraantiques/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php on line 56"


System - Configuration - Design results in:

"Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Helper_UnserializeArray' not found in /home/devastraantiques/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547"

Comment: Ok, what did you change before the problems occured?

Comment: Installed a number of Security "Supee" patches that weren't installed.
And updated a couple of Extensions "turpentine / minify js / image optimizer" and ran image optimizer to 100%.

That's when I noticed I couldn't access the "Design" tab.
I found I couldn't Edit / Add products later on.